# how to cascade uitableview's width to its custom table view cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I have a certain sized UIView used as a container of a UITableView. I use a subclass of UITableViewCell in my table view.

The problem is that my custom table view cell can not get the proper width from the UITableVIew. 
This is how I create the table view
`categoryListView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:categoryListContainer.bounds style:(UITableViewStylePlain)];`

This is how I create the custom table view cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == categoryListView) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCategoryListIdentifier";

        MenuCategoryListCellView *cell = (MenuCategoryListCellView*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            // create dynamically
            cell = [[MenuCategoryListCellView alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        ....
```

I wish to be able to get the correct cell bounds to in my MenuCategoryListCellView's initWithStyle method to draw my UI controls. But I don't know how to pass the value down.

Help will be appreciated!

Leo

Answer (score 0):

The system will send the `layoutSubviews` message to your cell when the cell is resized.  Override that method to lay out the UI controls according to the cell's current size.